# Angular Directive with ng-include template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, angularjs-ng-include

I've defined the following directive
I've defined the following dirctive in my js file:

```
.directive('tabContent',function(){    
                return {
                restrict: 'E',
                template:'<div ng-if="view==\'card" ng-include="card.html"></div>'
            }
        })
```

and than used it in my html:`<tabContent></tabContent>`
but all I got is a remark `<!--div--><!--ng-if--><!--ng-include-->`
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing escaped ' on card in your string and `ng-include` requires single quotes as well, since it will parse your url as an expression.

```
template:'<div ng-if="view==\'card\'" ng-include="\'card.html\'"></div>'
```

Comment: the solution is more simple than I thought. Thanks

Comment: @omer727 happy to help!